Why ARM NEON intrinsics are not faster than plain C++ for finding legal Othello moves?
I wrote a method with NEON to accelerate my code for an Othello game engine.
I expected a speedup from SIMD vectors, but no gain speed. nada :-(
I'm running this on an M3 with Xcode 16, Clang/LLVM 16, with
-Ofast -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math
I test my program with real example of game ±1/2h or more than billion call routine
It's only simple instructions, and, or, shift... on 64bits
I don't understand... how should I program this method for speed?
original code :
unsigned long long RXBitBoard::get_legal_moves(const unsigned long long p_discs, const unsigned long long o_discs) {
    
    
    const unsigned long long inner_o_discs = o_discs & 0x7E7E7E7E7E7E7E7EULL;
    
    
    /* direction W */
    unsigned long long
    flipped  = (p_discs >> 1) & inner_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >> 1) & inner_o_discs;
    
    unsigned long long adjacent_o_discs = inner_o_discs & (inner_o_discs >> 1);
    
    flipped |= (flipped >> 2) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >> 2) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    unsigned long long legals = flipped >> 1;
    
    
    //    /* direction _E*/
    //    flipped  = (p_discs << 1) & inner_o_discs;
    //    flipped |= (flipped << 1) & inner_o_discs;
    //
    //    adjacent_o_discs = inner_o_discs & (inner_o_discs << 1);
    //
    //    flipped |= (flipped << 2) & adjacent_o_discs;
    //    flipped |= (flipped << 2) & adjacent_o_discs;
    //
    //    legals |= flipped << 1;
    
    // trick
    /* direction _E */
    flipped = (p_discs << 1);
    legals |= ((flipped + inner_o_discs) & ~flipped);
    
    
    /* direction S */
    flipped  = (p_discs >>  8) & o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >>  8) & o_discs;
    
    adjacent_o_discs = o_discs & (o_discs >> 8);
    
    flipped |= (flipped >> 16) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >> 16) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    legals |= flipped >> 8;
    
    
    /* direction N */
    flipped  = (p_discs <<  8) & o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped <<  8) & o_discs;
    
    adjacent_o_discs = o_discs & (o_discs << 8);
    
    flipped |= (flipped << 16) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped << 16) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    legals |= flipped << 8;
    
    
    /* direction NE */
    flipped  = (p_discs >>  7) & inner_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >>  7) & inner_o_discs;
    
    adjacent_o_discs = inner_o_discs & (inner_o_discs >> 7);
    
    flipped |= (flipped >> 14) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >> 14) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    legals |= flipped >> 7;
    
    
    /* direction SW */
    flipped  = (p_discs <<  7) & inner_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped <<  7) & inner_o_discs;
    
    adjacent_o_discs = inner_o_discs & (inner_o_discs << 7);
    
    flipped |= (flipped << 14) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped << 14) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    legals |= flipped << 7;
    
    
    /* direction NW */
    flipped  = (p_discs >>  9) & inner_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >>  9) & inner_o_discs;
    
    adjacent_o_discs = inner_o_discs & (inner_o_discs >> 9);
    
    flipped |= (flipped >> 18) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped >> 18) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    legals |= flipped >> 9;
    
    
    /* direction SE */
    flipped  = (p_discs <<  9) & inner_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped <<  9) & inner_o_discs;
    
    adjacent_o_discs = inner_o_discs & (inner_o_discs << 9);
    
    flipped |= (flipped << 18) & adjacent_o_discs;
    flipped |= (flipped << 18) & adjacent_o_discs;
    
    legals |= flipped << 9;
    
    //Removes existing discs
    legals &= ~(p_discs | o_discs);
    
    return legals;
    
}

My NEON code
unsigned long long RXBitBoard::get_legal_moves(const unsigned long long p_discs, const unsigned long long o_discs ) {
    
    const uint64x2_t pp_discs = vdupq_n_u64(p_discs);
    const uint64x2_t oo_discs = vdupq_n_u64(o_discs);
    
    const uint64x2_t inner_oo_discs = vdupq_n_u64(o_discs & 0x7E7E7E7E7E7E7E7EULL);

    
    //horizontals directions -1, +1
    static const int64x2_t shift_1 = {-1, 1};
    static const int64x2_t shift_2 = {-2, 2};
    
    uint64x2_t
    flipped = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_1), inner_oo_discs);
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_1), inner_oo_discs));

    uint64x2_t 
    adjacent_oo_discs = vandq_u64(inner_oo_discs, vshlq_u64(inner_oo_discs, shift_1));

    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_2), adjacent_oo_discs));
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_2), adjacent_oo_discs));

    uint64x2_t legals = vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_1);

    //verticals directions -8 , +8
    static const int64x2_t shift_8  = {-8,   8};
    static const int64x2_t shift_16 = {-16, 16};

    flipped = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_8), oo_discs);
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_8), oo_discs));
    
    adjacent_oo_discs = vandq_u64(oo_discs, vshlq_u64(oo_discs, shift_8));
    
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_16), adjacent_oo_discs));
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_16), adjacent_oo_discs));

    legals = vorrq_u64(legals, vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_8));

    //diagonals directions -7 , +7
    static const int64x2_t shift_7  = {-7,   7};
    static const int64x2_t shift_14 = {-14, 14};

    flipped = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_7), inner_oo_discs);
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_7), inner_oo_discs));

    adjacent_oo_discs = vandq_u64(inner_oo_discs, vshlq_u64(inner_oo_discs, shift_7));

    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_14), adjacent_oo_discs));
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_14), adjacent_oo_discs));

    legals = vorrq_u64(legals, vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_7));
    
    //diagonals directions -9 , +9
    static const int64x2_t shift_9  = {-9,   9};
    static const int64x2_t shift_18 = {-18, 18};

    flipped = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_9), inner_oo_discs);
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_9), inner_oo_discs));

    adjacent_oo_discs = vandq_u64(inner_oo_discs, vshlq_u64(inner_oo_discs, shift_9));

    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_18), adjacent_oo_discs));
    flipped = vorrq_u64(flipped, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_18), adjacent_oo_discs));

    legals = vorrq_u64(legals, vshlq_u64(flipped, shift_9));
    
    
    return ((vgetq_lane_u64(legals, 0) | vgetq_lane_u64(legals, 1)) & ~(p_discs | o_discs));

}

i even wrote a interleave version

../...
    uint64x2_t
    flip_h = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_1), inner_oo_discs);
    uint64x2_t
    flip_v = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_8), oo_discs);
    uint64x2_t
    flip_d7 = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_7), inner_oo_discs);
    uint64x2_t
    flip_d9 = vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(pp_discs, shift_9), inner_oo_discs);

    flip_h = vorrq_u64(flip_h, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flip_h, shift_1), inner_oo_discs));
    flip_v = vorrq_u64(flip_v, vandq_u64(vshlq_u64(flip_v, shift_8), oo_discs));

.../...

I can expect a speed gain, no?

-ffast-math affects float and double.

The compiler is probably simply better at writing simd code than you are, optimisers are pretty impressive these days

Try doing clang -fno-vectorize -fno-slp-vectorize file.c to see how your initial code would have performed had it not been auto-vectorized.

TLDR: Because C++ compilers are good!  CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”

Both versions compile to 84 instructions for ARM64 with Clang 16 -O3: https://godbolt.org/z/6rYaK7Pqe
It auto-vectorizes the scalar version.
I didn't try to check how similar the two versions are, but both do a lot of uslh and orr on vectors, so I wouldn't be surprised if the asm is pretty much equivalent.  If so, apparently modern Clang is good enough that there's no benefit to manual vectorization.  At least not the way you did it; I didn't look at the intrinsics or how they compiled to see if there's room to improve.
Some instructions have different throughput costs than others, and the dependency chains among them can affect performance.  In general having the same instruction count is no guarantee of similar performance.  But with two functions doing the same work with 128-bit vectors, they probably are doing it in a pretty similar way, with pretty similar instruction mix and pattern of dependency chains.

You could save one load by getting shift_2 from a left-shift of shift_1, instead of a separate static const.  Or at least group your constants into an array of int64x2_t so it doesn't need to do separate adrp instructions for each variable.

LLVM docs say the vectorizer is enabled by default and able to spot reductions that use the OR operator (among others) and vectorise them. And this code appears to be manually unrolled loops doing bitwise OR reductions. https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#reductions

@Dunes: Yes, Clang enables vectorization at -O2 and higher.  (Unlike GCC where -O2 only enables limited vectorization, like easy cases where the loop count is a multiple of the vector width, and older GCC didn't enable any vectorization at all until -O3.) And yes, Clang's vectorize is quite good, able to invent shuffles to get different scalar values into the halves of a 128-bit vector.  Also able to even invent some vector constants here. The only question here is how similar Clang's auto-vectorization strategy is to the OP's manual strategy. Big-picture, yes Clang vectorized no problem

There just might be a better algorithm for finding the legal moves (I don't have enough time to really understand the algorithm, as I'm confused about the variable names flipped vs the intention legal_moves).
If the purpose is to find all to possible positions, where to place a new 'P' given opponent discs 'o' and own discs 'p', then one could transform the table to all positions where the computation is most efficient.
Given a row --ooppoo, one can find with o & (p << 1) those places that start a span of legal os. Then, a = o + (o & (p << 1)) propagates that bit to the left over all the opponent bits, landing either to outside the table (using SIMD and not SWAR), or to an unoccupied bit or on top of other own element p. Thus the R->L is probably most efficiently handled with
  auto R_L_valid = (o + (o & (p << 1))) & ~p;

To compute L_R_valid, one will bitreverse the tables o,p (rbit) and do the same computation, then bitreverse back to the original position. (The & ~p can be postponed as a common factor).
To compute TopBottom and BottomTop directions, one should transpose the bit matrices, for which there exists a 9-instruction method for two 8x8 bit matrices.
For the diagonals, I don't have unfortunately that good algorithms; one could use variadic shifts to align diagonals to verticals -- and then use the same 3-instruction innerloop. But for each diagonal there will be now two transformed half-tables.
The \ diagonals are caught by

   a b c d e f g h      a b c d e f g h     . . . . . . . .
   i j k l m n o p      j k l m n o p .     . . . . . . . i
   q r s t u v w x      s t u v w x . .     . . . . . . q r
   y z 0 1 2 3 4 5  --> 1 2 3 4 5 . . .  +  . . . . . y z 0
   a b c d e f g h      e f g h . . . .     . . . . a b c d
   i j k l m n o p      n o p . . . . .     . . . i j k l m
   q r s t u v w x      w x . . . . . .     . . q r s t u v
   y z 0 1 2 3 4 5      5 . . . . . . .     . y z 0 1 2 3 4

auto upper = variadic_rotate_left(p);
auto lower = variadic_rotate_right(p);
auto both = transpose(upper | lower);
diagonal_SE_1 = both & k_transposed_upper_fixed_mask;
diagonal_SE_2 = both & ~k_transposed_upper_fixed_mask;
diagonal_NW_1 = bit_reverse(diagonal_SE_1);
diagonal_NW_2 = bit_reverse(diagonal_SE_2);

// note that k_transposed_upper_fixed_mask == k_upper_fixed_mask

Perhaps the regularity of this approach can bring some speed benefits.
